# Unexpected behavior while deleting row from DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

i am using below code to delete selected row form `DataGridView` but I have problem which is 
that this code will always remove half of the checked rows

like if i checked two row out of two then it will delete one row and leave the other one

```
private void B_DeleteProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("selected row deleted", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow RowToDelete in DGV_INVOICE.Rows)
        {
            object Cell = RowToDelete.Cells["Edit_Checkbox"].Value;

            if (Cell.ToString() == "True")
            {
                DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Remove(RowToDelete);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are removing from the very collection you are iterating.

Comment: First find those rows, then remove them. You can do it simply using linq.

Comment: @Plutonix please i do not understand your point would you mind to explain it more ?

Comment: @RezaAghaei can you post a link for something saniler to what you said.. casue linq is something new to me

Comment: You are not allowed to modify the collection your foreach loop iterates. Either use a reverse for loop or collect the rows in a list and delete in a second loop!

Comment: The internal implementations of `DataGridViewRowCollection` **lets you** modify the collection in a foreach loop, so technically **you are allowed** to modify the collection during a foreach loop and you will not receive an exception. **But** if you perform it like you are doing in your code, only half of items will be removed.

Comment: Iterate a collection in a `for` loop (not `foreach`) from the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the collection which you are iterating on. usually it causes an invalid operation exception, but not in this case.

The internal implementations of `DataGridViewRowCollection` **lets you** modify the collection in a foreach loop, so technically **you are allowed** to modify the collection during a foreach loop and you will not receive an exception. **But** if you perform it like you are doing in your code, only half of items will be removed.

Its because after removing the item at index 0, index of items will decrease one and the previous item at index 1 goes to index 0 and so on, then the iterator uses index 1 for next item while the previous item at index 1 is at index 0 now. This way one item will be removed and one item will be bypassed until the end of collection.

To solve the problem you can find items which you want to remove and keep them in a list and then iterate on the list and remove them from original collection. You can use linq `Where` to find the rows and `ToList` to store them in the mentioned list and then remove them:

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[1].Value == true)
    .ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(x);
    });
```

**You can also use a reverse for loop**, but I think above method is more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very details information and explanation :) specially for the critical point about index decreasing